# Foreach loop solution in Php or JavaScript

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I want to create a foreach loop where I compare a value A with a different value (Value (n)) with each loop , and if the value A is greater than the value (n) the loop should continue till the items in loop are finished.

But the catch is that I want the value of A to be subtracted from by the value (n) it was compared to, with each interaction. So that in the next iteration
Value A is less than it was in the previous loop
i.e new value of A =  value A - Value (n).

```
 public function create(Request $data, User $user): Payment
{
    return DB::transaction(function () use($data, $user) {
        $payment = $user->payments->create([
            'amount_paid'   => $data->amount,
            'pay_method'    => $data->payMethod,
            'comment'       => $data->comment,
            'patient_id'    => $data->patientId,
            'visit_id'      => $data->visitId,
        ]);

        $totalPayments = $payment->visitPayments($payment->visit);

        $payment->visit->update([
            'total_paid' => $totalPayments
        ]);

        $totalPaymentsforPrescriptions = $totalPayments;

        $prescriptions = $payment->visit->prescriptions;

        foreach($prescriptions as $prescription) {
            &$totalPaymentsforPrescriptions = $totalPaymentsforPrescriptions - $prescription->hmo_bill;
            
        }
        return $payment;
    });
}
```

Don't know how to return the new value of A to the ongoing foreach loop.

I am trying to change the variable outside the loop by reference with the ampersand(&) but I am getting an error(red underline) that it is unexpected.

I can't seem to figure it out yet. Lack of knowledge I guess.

Comment: How does the current version of your code look like?

Comment: Have you tried a `for` loop instead of `foreach`. Or you can just declare `A` and `n` before the loop starts? You didn't explain what you tried so far. See also [ask]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even know which way to go that's why. but I have tried something so I have edited my question

Comment: You don't need to pass by reference because this doesn't involve passing the variable into a function. It's still in scope already

Comment: P.s. unless you've deliberately abbreviated this code, you never use `$totalPaymentsforPrescriptions` after the loop ends, so it's unclear what you're actually trying to achieve, or how you're observing any results from your loop

Comment: @ITgoldman why do we need "global" here? There's currently no evidence of needing to pull in a value from outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, using a reference (&) in a foreach loop is typically done with the looped variable itself, not with a variable outside the loop. In your case you should try this code, hope it works

```
public function create(Request $data, User $user): Payment
{
    return DB::transaction(function () use ($data, $user) {
        $payment = $user->payments->create([
            'amount_paid'   => $data->amount,
            'pay_method'    => $data->payMethod,
            'comment'       => $data->comment,
            'patient_id'    => $data->patientId,
            'visit_id'      => $data->visitId,
        ]);

        $totalPayments = $payment->visitPayments($payment->visit);

        $payment->visit->update([
            'total_paid' => $totalPayments
        ]);

        $totalPaymentsforPrescriptions = $totalPayments;

        $prescriptions = $payment->visit->prescriptions;

        foreach ($prescriptions as $prescription) {
            if ($totalPaymentsforPrescriptions > $prescription->hmo_bill) {
                $totalPaymentsforPrescriptions -= $prescription->hmo_bill;
            }
        }

        return $payment;
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks for this. I ended up using the array reduce function in Php. So I could keep returning the amount after deducting from it.